# How to easily rbind nested list with different depths?

Tags: r, data.table, nested-lists, rbind

I have a dataset where some of the data is in a nested list.
The problem is that the depth of the lists varies, and it is impossible to know in advance the depths.

Here is an example (note: in the original dataset, none of the list are named):

`

```
list1 <- list(
  list("data1"), 
  list(
    list("data2")
  ), 
  list(c("data3", "data4", "data5")),
  list(
    list(
      "data6"
    )
  ), 
  list(c("data7", "data8")), 
  list(
    list(
      list(c("data9", "data10", "data11", "data12"))
    )
  ),
  list("data13")
)
```

`

My goal is to extract all the "data..." from this list into a new dataframe (extract in a sense that I want to rbind them):

| nrows | data |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | data1 |
| 2 | data2 |
| 3 | data3, data4, data5 |
| 4 | data6 |
| 5 | data7, data8 |
| 6 | data9, data10, data11, data12 |
| 7 | data13 |

I tried many options (repeated unlist/map/lapply(list1, function(l) l[[1]]) then bind_rows or do.call(rbind, ...), etc..),  but none of them worked. The thing that bothers me the most is that I don't know why I can't solve it.

So my question is the following: what is the easiest way to rbind nested lists with different depths?

Comment: What is the data type of `data` supposed to be? Character?

Comment: Yes, charachters (names of different authors..).

Answer (score 1):

`unlist()` each sublist and the rest will be easy. To get the data as a character *vector* you can then apply `toString()`:

```
data.frame(
  nr = seq_along(list1),
  data = sapply(list1, \(x) toString(unlist(x)))
)


#   nr                          data
# 1  1                         data1
# 2  2                         data2
# 3  3           data3, data4, data5
# 4  4                         data6
# 5  5                  data7, data8
# 6  6 data9, data10, data11, data12
# 7  7                        data13
```

Answer (score 1):

**1)** Assuming you want a column whose elements are character vectors try this:

```
DF <- data.frame(nrows = seq_along(list1))
DF$data <- lapply(list1, unlist)

str(DF)
## 'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ nrows: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
##  $ data :List of 7
##   ..$ : chr "data1"
##   ..$ : chr "data2"
##   ..$ : chr  "data3" "data4" "data5"
##   ..$ : chr "data6"
##   ..$ : chr  "data7" "data8"
##   ..$ : chr  "data9" "data10" "data11" "data12"
##   ..$ : chr "data13"
```

**1a)** This variation also works.  Using I(,,,) is critical here as without it the code would issue an error.

```
DF <- data.frame(nrows = seq_along(list1), data = I(lapply(list1, unlist)))
str(DF)
## 'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ nrows: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
##  $ data :List of 7
##   ..$ : chr "data1"
##   ..$ : chr "data2"
##   ..$ : chr  "data3" "data4" "data5"
##   ..$ : chr "data6"
##   ..$ : chr  "data7" "data8"
##   ..$ : chr  "data9" "data10" "data11" "data12"
##   ..$ : chr "data13"
##   ..- attr(*, "class")= chr "AsIs"
```

**2)** If, instead, you want a character column in which each element of the `data` column is a single comma-space separated string or comma-separated string then after running (1) above run one of these:

```
DF$data <- sapply(DF$data, toString)
str(DF)
## 'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ nrows: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
##  $ data : chr  "data1" "data2" "data3, data4, data5" "data6" ...

DF$data <- sapply(DF$data, paste, collapse = ",")
str(DF)
## 'data.frame':   7 obs. of  2 variables:
##  $ nrows: int  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
##  $ data : chr  "data1" "data2" "data3,data4,data5" "data6" ...
```

Answer (score 1):

`lapply()` a recursive unlist and then just pass the resulting list to `tibble()` as a convenient way to get it into a data frame (a tibble is a type of data frame).

```r
list1 <- list(
  list("data1"), 
  list(
    list("data2")
  ), 
  list(c("data3", "data4", "data5")),
  list(
    list(
      "data6"
    )
  ), 
  list(c("data7", "data8")), 
  list(
    list(
      list(c("data9", "data10", "data11", "data12"))
    )
  ),
  list("data13")
)

## consider piping to as.data.frame if you specifically 
## want that format
new_list <- lapply(list1, unlist, recursive = TRUE)

dplyr::tibble(data = new_list)
#> # A tibble: 7 × 1
#>   data     
#>   <list>   
#> 1 <chr [1]>
#> 2 <chr [1]>
#> 3 <chr [3]>
#> 4 <chr [1]>
#> 5 <chr [2]>
#> 6 <chr [4]>
#> 7 <chr [1]>
```

<sup>Created on 2022-12-14 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Answer (score 0):

There's a very nice function in the collapse package for this, unlist2d

Output from unlist2d(list1) is

```
       .id.1 .id.2 .id.3 .id.4   V1     V2     V3     V4
    1     1     1    NA    NA  data1   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
    2     2     1     1    NA  data2   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
    3     3     1    NA    NA  data3  data4  data5   <NA>
    4     4     1     1    NA  data6   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
    5     5     1    NA    NA  data7  data8   <NA>   <NA>
    6     6     1     1     1  data9 data10 data11 data12
    7     7     1    NA    NA data13   <NA>   <NA>   <NA>
```

There are options to work with the column and row names

Answer (score 0):

Another option using `rrapply()` in package `rrapply`:

```
rrapply::rrapply(list1, how = "melt")

#>   L1 L2   L3   L4                         value
#> 1  1  1 <NA> <NA>                         data1
#> 2  2  1    1 <NA>                         data2
#> 3  3  1 <NA> <NA>           data3, data4, data5
#> 4  4  1    1 <NA>                         data6
#> 5  5  1 <NA> <NA>                  data7, data8
#> 6  6  1    1    1 data9, data10, data11, data12
#> 7  7  1 <NA> <NA>                        data13
```